# Does Closed XML support GetPivotData Formula?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I always getting syntax error when getting the value of a cell which has a formula of GetPivotData. Does ClosedXML support this? If not, could you suggest a better framework to handle the excel manipulation? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't support the `GetPivotData` formula.

Suggestion (as requested): Handle the source programmatically and calculate the required information yourself, e.g. with `Linq`.